# How to stop scratching the bed and print properly on an Ender 3 V2

Tags: troubleshooting, hardware

I am new to 3D printing, and I just put together the printer yesterday, and I spent a while trying to level it, but if I move the bed too low when it moves it gets stuck on the motor for it in the back, but if I move it just barely high enough to not do that, the nozzle hits the bed while printing and scratches the bed.

When I used Auto Home though, the nozzle was right around 1 mm above the bed like it said it should be, what should I do?

Comment: How do you level your bed?

Comment: Send it back. You printer is FUBAR.